# Knapsack Problem sorting the array based on profit per unit weight

Tags: c++

So i have written a code for knapsack problem but i don't know how am i supposed to sort the profit(p) and weight(p) arrays based on the profit per unit weight (arrange array)?Also any other way of approaching the problem i appreciated please post below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void knapsack(float w[],int m,int n){
    float result[n];//this array holds the final result
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        result[i]=0.0;
    }
    int rem=m;
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(w[j]>rem){
            break;
        }
        else{
            result[j]=1;
            rem=rem-w[j];
        }
    }
    if(j<n){
        result[j]=rem/w[j];
    }
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        cout<<result[k]<<" ";
    }
}

int main(){
    int n,m;
    cout<<"Enter the number of items"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter capacity of bag"<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"Enter the profits"<<endl;
    float p[n],w[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>p[i];//this array holds the profit of each item
    }
    cout<<"Enter the respective weights"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>w[i];//this array holds the respective weights of items
    }
    float arrange[n];//This array contains profit per unit weight ratio
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arrange[i]=p[i]/w[i];
        cout<<arrange[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    knapsack(w,m,n);

}
```

Comment: Do I understand this right?  The index describes the item? Say p[i] and w[i] are the information of one item. One way would be to sort and array of indices. This way you would keep the information which item has this price and weight. You could use this array to create orderd p and w arrays.

Comment: yeah but how do i use the p[i]/w[i] array to sort my profit and weight arrays?

Comment: If an answer solved your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

As @Cool Dudde suggested switching from (struct of arrays) to array of structs could make the code easier to understand.

But then you can go further and adapt knapsack to the new array of struct:

- change `knapsack` to work with iterators instead of arrays (pointers are randome-access iterators, so you could test your changes with little change to the rest of the code). The signatur of `knapsack` will look somethink like this:

  ```
  template<class It>
  void knapsack(It begin, It end, int m);
  ```
- use an `struct`/`class` Item with the properties `weight` and `price` and maybe some identifier (could be an int or string). I think this much cleaner then using an `int[2]`.
- then use `std::vector<Item> items` and the solution from @Cool Dudde:

  ```
  std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), [](const Item& a, const Item& b) {return (a.price/a.weight) < (b.price/b.weight);});
  ```
- `items.begin()` will give you not a suitable iterator for `knapsack`, but you could use an transform-iterator to access the weight in items. (/or you make a new array, copy the results of the sort into it, and then use this as input for `knapsack`)

Answer (score 1):

you might have more success by using a `std::vector<int[2]>` to hold your profits and weights together, which will give you a malleable vector integer arrays (you could use any two integer data structure other than int[2] here), then using the std::sort function.

The sort function tends to be a bit rough to understand at times, and I do get it wrong at times but I believe this is how you would use it in this situation;

```
std::vector<int[2]> items;
std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), [](int* a, int* b) {return (a[0]/a[1]) < (b[0]/b[1]);});
```

where a[0] & b[0] will be some items profit, and a[1] and b[1] will be some items weight.